# Map category parent id self referencing table structure to EF Core entity

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework-core, categories, self-referencing-table

Database Table:

[image]

I tried this approach to map the category table to EF core:

```c#
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Category>(entity =>
    {
        entity
            .HasMany(e => e.Children)
            .WithOne(e => e.Parent) 
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.ParentId);
    });
}
```

Entity:

```c#
[Table("Category"]
public class Category : EntityBase
{
    [DataType(DataType.Text), MaxLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int? ParentId { get; set; }

    public int? Order { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ParentId")]
    public virtual Category Parent { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Category> Children { get; set; }
}
```

Then in the repository:

```
public override IEnumerable<Category> GetAll()
{ 
    IEnumerable<Category> categories = Table.Where(x => x.Parent == null).Include(x => x.Children).ThenInclude(x=> x.Children);
    return categories;
}
```

This worked but anything after 3 levels was not returned no matter how many times you call Include() or ThenInclude().

I ended up writing the code myself to populate the child categories with a recursive function:

```c#
public override IEnumerable<Category> GetAll()
{
    IEnumerable<Category> categories = Table.Where(x => x.Parent == null).ToList();
    categories = Traverse(categories);
    return categories;
}

private IEnumerable<Category> Traverse(IEnumerable<Category> categories)
{
    foreach(var category in categories)
    {
        var subCategories = Table.Where(x => x.ParentId == category.Id).ToList();
        category.Children = subCategories;
        category.Children = Traverse(category.Children).ToList();
    }
    return categories;
}
```

Does anyone know a better way to write a stored procedure to get the table hierarchy and map to the Category entity I have provided in the example?

Comment: This is how I do that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63577137/804385

Answer (score 25, accepted):

EF (and LINQ in general) has issues loading tree like data due to lack of recursive expression/CTE support.

But in case you want to load the **whole** tree (as opposed to filtered tree branch), there is a simple `Include` based solution. All you need is a single `Include` and then the EF navigation property fixup will do the work for you. And when you need to get only the root nodes as in your sample, the trick is to apply the filter after the query has been materialized (and navigation properties being fixed) by switching to LINQ to Objects context (using `AsEnumerable()` as usual).

So the following should produce the desired result with single SQL query:

```
public override IEnumerable<Category> GetAll()
{ 
    return Table
       .AsEnumerable()
       .Where(x => x.ParentId == null)
       .ToList();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, your solution worked perfectly.

Comment: DV-er is probably someone who thinks you should create a recursive method firing umpteen queries. But Ivan, shouldn't this even work without the `Include`?

Comment: Hi  @Gert, Good point, actually it does! Now I recall we have discussed this behavior for EF6. The only difference is that leaf nodes gets `null` children w/o `Include` and empty collection with. Of course if the collection members are always initialized, there is no difference.

Comment: Testing this now in my code-i think I've probably lost 4-5 hours googling this only to find it mentioned in a comment on another answer.. :/

Comment: OMG. you king :)

Comment: thanks a lot mate, I was losing my mind haha, cheers  idk .. EF Core breaking changes are frustrating .. i see the benefits but some lacking features from EF6 are crazy.

Comment: This code loads the entire table into memory and filters on server side.

Comment: OMG. You are real king. Thank you.

Comment: I'm confused, OP asks how to get all children, yet there is no code for this here, only a brief mention without code to clarify, the only code in this answer, is to do something he didn't ask (get only root nodes)

Comment: @PandaWood The code which does what OP asks is `Table.AsEnumerable()` (or directly `ToList()` etc.), i.e. enumerating the query which returns the **whole** table (**all** records). As I wrote in the answer, *"then the EF navigation property fixup will do the work for you"*, so at the end you have your model parent/children loaded and linked together in memory.