# EF Core 2.1: Self-referencing entity with one to many relationship generates additional column

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, one-to-many, ef-fluent-api, ef-core-2.1

I have the following entity:

```cs
public class Level
{
    public int LevelId { get; set; }
    public int? ParentLevelId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual Level Parent { get; set; }
    public virtual HashSet<Level> Children { get; set; }   
}
```

What I am having trouble here, is the `Children` property, which is configured like this in Fluent API:

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<Level>()
    .HasOne(x => x.Parent)
    .WithMany(x => x.Children)
    .HasForeignKey(x => x.ParentLevelId);
```

This results in some additional column being added by the migration:

```cs
migrationBuilder.AddColumn<int>(
    name: "LevelId1",
    table: "Level",
    nullable: true);

migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
    name: "IX_Level_LevelId1",
    table: "Level",
    column: "LevelId1");

migrationBuilder.AddForeignKey(
    name: "FK_Level_Level_LevelId1",
    table: "Level",
    column: "LevelId1",
    principalTable: "Level",
    principalColumn: "LevelId",
    onDelete: ReferentialAction.Restrict);
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Edit: Question was marked as a possible duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46160780); however, in that case, the model generation works - the issue is loading the data. Whereas here, the issue is that an additional column is generated.

Comment: Is LevelId the PK? If so try adding the key annotation above the property like:

[Key]
public int LevelId {get;set;}

Comment: Is this all code or did you leave out other properties for brevity?

Comment: @dickrichie just tried adding the [Key] attribute, same thing happens.

Comment: @GertArnold I left out other stuff for brevity. I have some more string and DateTime properties, nothing complicated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Map category parent id self referencing table structure to EF Core entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46160780/map-category-parent-id-self-referencing-table-structure-to-ef-core-entity)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Something's messed up in your migration.  No repro when initializing that model:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;

namespace EfCoreTest
{

    public class Level
    {
        public int LevelId { get; set; }
        public int? ParentLevelId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual Level Parent { get; set; }
        public virtual HashSet<Level> Children { get; set; }
    }

    public class Db : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Level> levels { get; set; }


        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("server=.;database=EfCoreTest;Integrated Security=true");
            base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Level>()
                        .HasOne(x => x.Parent)
                        .WithMany(x => x.Children)
                        .HasForeignKey(x => x.ParentLevelId);

        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var db = new Db())
            {
                db.Database.EnsureDeleted();
                db.Database.EnsureCreated();

                Console.ReadKey();



            }

        }
    }
}
```

creates table:

```
CREATE TABLE [levels] (
    [LevelId] int NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    [ParentLevelId] int NULL,
    [Name] nvarchar(max) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_levels] PRIMARY KEY ([LevelId]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_levels_levels_ParentLevelId] FOREIGN KEY ([ParentLevelId]) REFERENCES [levels] ([LevelId]) ON DELETE NO ACTION
);
```

Added a Migration,

```
PM> Add-Migration InitialCreate
```

and still no repro:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations;

namespace EfCoreTest.Migrations
{
    public partial class InitialCreate : Migration
    {
        protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "levels",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    LevelId = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
                        .Annotation("SqlServer:ValueGenerationStrategy", SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn),
                    ParentLevelId = table.Column<int>(nullable: true),
                    Name = table.Column<string>(nullable: true)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_levels", x => x.LevelId);
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_levels_levels_ParentLevelId",
                        column: x => x.ParentLevelId,
                        principalTable: "levels",
                        principalColumn: "LevelId",
                        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Restrict);
                });

            migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
                name: "IX_levels_ParentLevelId",
                table: "levels",
                column: "ParentLevelId");
        }

        protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.DropTable(
                name: "levels");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I just dropped the db, deleted all migrations and created a new initial one. Same issue, it creates a LevelId property (key), ParentLevelId and that additional LevelId1.

Comment: Try being explicit and decorating your `Parent` property with `[ForeignKey("ParentLevelId")]` to tell Entity specifically that you want to use that column as the FK for that Navigation Property.

Comment: @DavideDeSantis Added a Migration.  Still no repro.

Comment: I just retried after the weekend, and all of a sudden it works. I didn't change anything, did the same thing as last week (e.g. dropping the db, deleting all migrations, recreating an initial migration). What didn't work multiple times last week now works perfectly, no idea why. Thanks anyway for your help!

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft and how can you retrieve all data in a hierarchical form?

Comment: The If you retrieve all the entities, EF will fix-up the relationships.

Comment: Hi @DavidBrowne-Microsoft, I have a similar configuration and it was, but my problem is that I can't insert an entity without setting the parentId `SqlException: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY SAME TABLE constraint`. This is the error I am currently getting. Any suggestions will be welcomed

Comment: Post a repro in a new question.