# How to implement self-recursive parent-child relationship data loading with eager loading policy in Entity Framework Core 2.2?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core

I use Entity Framework Core 2.2 and code-first approach. In database there is a table, let's simplify it as Department.

```
public class Department
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ? ParentId { get; set; }
    public string DepartmentName { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Department> InnerDepartments { get; set; }
}
```

I defined configuration with Fluent API and it generated a structure I wanted.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
        modelBuilder.Entity<Department>().HasKey(p => p.Id);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Department>().HasMany(p => p.InnerDepartments)
            .WithOne(p => p.TopDepartment)
            .HasForeignKey(p => p.TopDepartmentId);

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

For example, I may have the following data.

```
Id  TopDepartmentId  DepartmentName
-----------------------------------------
1      NULL          Software Development
2       1            Mobile Development
3       1            Web Development
4       2            IOS Development
5       2            Android Development
6       4            Swift Development
7       4            Objective-C Development
```

I want to arrange data from this table to following structure:

```
public class DepartmentShortInfoModel
{
    public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
    public string DepartmentName { get; set; }
    public int DirectInnerDepartmentsCount { get; set; }
    public int IndirectInnerDepartmentsCount { get; set; }
}
```

That means that for each department customer wants to get the number of direct inner departments - (first-level-depth children count), for example, Mobile Department has 2 direct children - IOS and Android departments. In the same time, customer wants to know number of indirect inner departments, Mobile Department has 4 indirect children - IOS, Android, Swift, Objective-C, as Swift and Objective-C are children of children for Mobile Department.

I tried to implement this feature with recursive tree traversal algorithm.

```
private int GetChildrenDepartmentCount(
        Department department, 
        bool useRecursionForTraversal = false)
    {
        int numberOfChildrenInCurrentLevel = department.InnerDepartments?.Count() ?? 0;

        if (useRecursionForTraversal == false)
            return numberOfChildrenInCurrentLevel;

        if (folder.Children != null)
            return numberOfChildrenInCurrentLevel +
                folder.Children.Select(p => GetChildrenDepartmentCount(p, useRecursionForTraversal)).Sum();
        else return numberOfChildrenInCurrentLevel ;
    }
```

I load data from DbContext with Eager-loading.

```
using(var context = new DepartmentContext(options))
{
            var department = context.Departments.Include(p => p.InnerDepartments)
                                                .First(p => p.Id == 1);
}
```

However, problem is that EF loads only 1-st level children (Mobile and Web) and for the following levels returns NULL in InnerDepartments property.

How can I request EF to load inner-levels too? I read similar questions where community suggested to use `SelectMany` , but problem here is in NULL on InnerDepartments property, not in getting inner values with LINQ query.

Comment: The only standard efficient way of eager loading all levels is to load the whole table in memory. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46160780/map-category-parent-id-self-referencing-table-structure-to-ef-core-entity/46161259#46161259. Of course you can always go with SP/raw SQL using recursive CTE or whatever hierarchical SQL query construct is supported by the target database(s).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication116
{
    class Program
    {
        static DataTable dt;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("TopDepartmentId", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("DepartmentName", typeof(string));

            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1, null, "Software Development" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 2, 1, "Mobile Development" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 3, 1, "Web Development" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 4, 2, "IOS Development" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 5, 2, "Android Development" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 6, 4, "Swift Development" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 7, 4, "Objective-C Development" });

            GetTree(null, 0);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        static void GetTree(int? parent, int level)
        {
            DataRow[] children = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<int?>("TopDepartmentId") == parent).ToArray();
            foreach (DataRow child in children)
            {
                int childId = child.Field<int>("Id");
                Console.WriteLine("{0}ID : '{1}', TopDepartmentId : '{2}', DepartmentName : '{3}'", 
                    new string(' ', 5 * level), //ident each level
                    childId.ToString(), 
                    (child.Field<object>("TopDepartmentId") == null) ? "BOSS" : child.Field<int?>("TopDepartmentId").ToString(),
                    child.Field<string>("DepartmentName"));

                GetTree(childId, level + 1);
            }
        }

    }

}
```